# Notice: Undefined index: file in

Tags: php, sql, fileupload

subjects.php

```
 $subjid = $_POST["subjects"];

    if (is_array($subjid) || is_object($subjid)) {
        foreach ($subjid as $subj)  {
            if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                echo $_POST["file"]."\n\n";

                if (isset( $_POST["file"]) ) {
                    /* ... proceed ... */
                    echo "F";
                } else echo "/////////////////////////////////";

                $sql = "INSERT INTO Student_Files (StudentID, SubjectID, File) VALUES(".$_SESSION["StudentID"].", ".$subj.", ".$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].");"; 

                echo $sql;
                //$sql = "INSERT INTO Student_Files (StudentID, SubjectID, File) VALUES(".$_SESSION["StudentID"].", ".$subj.", '".$_POST["file"]."');"; 
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            }
            /*else {
                echo "NOT SUBMITTED";
            }*/
        } 
    }
    else {
        echo "PROB";
    }
```

files.php

```
    <form action="subjects.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p><strong>Select your subjects.hold down the ctrl or cmd key to select more than one option.</strong></p> 

        <select name="subjects[]" multiple> 
<?php               
        $sql= "SELECT SubjectID, Subject FROM Subjects";
        if($result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
?>      
            <option value="<?php echo $row['SubjectID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['Subject']; ?></option>
<?php
        }
        } else echo "PROBLEM";
?>              
        </select>

        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type='submit' value='Submit' name="submit"/>

    </form>
```

Цель программы сохранить отправленный файл в датабазе. При запуске кода выводиться это

> Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/elz/public_html/Project/process/subjects.php on line 13
>   /////////////////////////////////INSERT INTO Student_Files (StudentID, SubjectID, File) VALUES(18, 1, /tmp/phpS8nUiO);
>
> Notice: Undefined index: file in /home/elz/public_html/Project/process/subjects.php on line 13
>   /////////////////////////////////INSERT INTO Student_Files (StudentID, SubjectID, File) VALUES(18, 2, /tmp/phpS8nUiO);

$_POST["file"] пустой, хотя файл был выбран.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что сама суть скрипта тут неверна.

Файл не содержится в массиве $_POST[''], он находится в массиве **$_FILES['']**

Что бы добраться до файла нужно сделать так:

```
var_dump($_FILES['file']);
```

Тогда вы и увидите сам файл.

А для работы с картинками есть вот такой файлик, очень помогает сохранять картинки на сервере и изменять их размер:

https://github.com/sanchiz-net/sanchiz-net-sandbox/tree/master/simple_image

Там же есть и пример того, как это всё работает.

Comment: Спасибо большоое